# simple mailto integrating query

Tags: php, mysql, post, input, mailto

OK I have a simple mail to where I am trying to email all my members based on a simple query.
Problem is I must be missing something due to the form just reloads and dose not send anything.

**email.php**

```
<form method="post" action="massemail.php">

        Subject:</br>
        <input type="text" name="subject" /><br />

        Message:</br>
        <textarea name="details"></textarea><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>
```

**massemail.php**

```
require 'core/init.php';
require_once "email.php"; 

$message = check_input($_POST['details']);
$subject = check_input($_POST['subject']);

$results = mysql_query('SELECT email from users');

while(list($email) = mysql_fetch_row($results))
{
  mail($email, '$subject', '$message');
}
```

**have tried**

```
    <?php
require 'core/init.php';
require_once "email.php"; 

$message = "test";
$subject = "123";

if ($results = mysql_query('SELECT email from users')) {

    while(list($email) = mysql_fetch_row($results)) {

  mail($email, '$subject', '$message');
}
?>
```

Comment: does it actually do anything? did you try to echo out the users email just for debugging in the loop?

Comment: its just showing the form not doing any action at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to **extract the email addresses from each row** instead of using the row itself. That can easily be achieved with `$row[0]` in your case since your query has always one column, though you should probably try to use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli) instead of the deprecated mysql.

Second, I would recommend calling `mail()` **once only**, to send one message to all people rather than one email per person! Why do you want to send the same email again and again like this? It is possible to use a comma-separated list of emails, as seen on the [PHP: mail - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

If you want to use mysql, your code could look something like this with [PHP Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and the handy [implode](https://www.php.net/function.implode) function:

```
require 'core/init.php'; // calls mysql_connect(...)
require_once "email.php";

$message = check_input($_POST['details']);
$subject = check_input($_POST['subject']);

if (mysql_ping()) { echo 'Ping worked'; } else { echo 'Ping failed'; } // DEBUG
$results = mysql_query('SELECT email from users');

$emails = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($results))
{
    array_push($emails, $row[0]);
}
echo implode(", ", $emails); // DEBUG
if (!empty($emails)) {
    mail(implode(", ", $emails), $subject, $message);
}
```

It seems to me (while chatting with you) that the whole mechanism of HTML Forms + PHP (GET and/or POST) is not clear to you. You should probably read about all this a bit more, and hopefully the code below helps you:

```
<?php
// Put requires here
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Demo form methods</h1>
<?php
if ((isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['body'])) || (isset($_GET['subject']) && isset($_GET['body']))) { 
    
    // Your code for sending an email could be here
    ?>

<h2>RESULTs</h2>
<ul>
    <li>POST
        <ul>
            <li>suject: <?php echo $_POST['subject']; ?></li>
            <li>suject: <?php echo $_POST['body']; ?></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>GET
        <ul>
            <li>suject: <?php echo $_GET['subject']; ?></li>
            <li>suject: <?php echo $_GET['body']; ?></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

    <?php
    // The code above is just to show you how the variables in GET/POST work

 } else { 

    // Below are two formulaires, you can keep one only of course!
    ?>

<h2>FORMs</h2>
<h3>GET method</h3>
<form method="get" action="email.php">
    Subject: <input name="subject" type="text"><br>
    Body: <input name="body" type="text"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send with GET">
</form>
<h3>POST method</h3>
<form method="post" action="email.php">
    Subject: <input name="subject" type="text"><br>
    Body: <input name="body" type="text"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send with POST">

</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to try and add `echo` statements to see what is happening, you can chose: `echo $row[0]` inside the while loop, or `echo implode(", ", $emails)` once after the while loop. Let me know how that goes, and if it all works for you: accept the answer! ;)

Comment: when it works i will accept answer, at the moment its not working but will try echo out the query.

Comment: Perhaps while you are debugging you can try to set the error reporting to get more warnings/errors if I made a typo in the code above, or something else is not working with your code. Have a look at [`error_reporting(E_ALL)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: will do, il give it a go now

Comment: Cool! Where is your call to `mysql_connect()` btw? in one of the `require`? You could try to add a call to [`mysql_ping()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php) at the top of the script, to see if the connection is fine!

Comment: for some reason when it goes to the massemail.php nothing comes up even tried echoing the query and error_reporting

Comment: Update my answer with the mysql_connect() call you were missing, and DEBUG statements

Comment: What do you mean? should i put a connection string strain in the code ?

Comment: Or in one of the `require`. Your code has to call [`mysql_connect()`](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) before you can call [`mysql_query()`](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Will edit my answer assuming the connection has been made earlier...

Comment: the require 'core/init.php'; file contains my connections

Comment: How does my edited answer work? How far in the code does it go? Add one echo every other line if you need to find out... Also, check that core/init.php and email.php have [no closing PHP tags to avoid trouble with headers](http://www.sitepoint.com/should-you-close-your-php-code-tags/) being already sent?

Comment: will try echo out the lines now as nothing is happing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45938/discussion-between-snooze92-and-beep)

Comment: I am glad! Did you figure out what was wrong, or re-started from scratch?

Comment: I started from scratch but your example helped me

Answer (score 0):

It's not sending the email because you are not parsing the query results properly.

```
//connect to MySQL using following line. This is the NEW and better way of doing it.
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if ($result = $mysqli->query('SELECT email from users')) { 
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){ 
            mail($row->email, $subject, $message);
        } 
    } 
    $result->close();
```

Comment: I know the OP shouldn't be using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, but you might consider providing your answer in that context, as right now, he wouldn't be about to use the code in your example, even though you have correctly demonstrated the problem.

Comment: Thanks for showing me some mysqli still not working but am going to run a echo on the query see what comes up